# how to plot a expenditure vs year in r

Tags: r

I have a dataset which has about 100,000 datapoints.
I want to plot two columns.

1. Y axis - Year
2. X axis - Sales

Sample Data:

Sales   Year
22       2016
10       2016
3.99     2017
8.99     2017
12.99    2017
8.00     2016
12.00    2017
5.00     2016
22       2017
50       2016
53       2017

Im using the following code

```
plot(subset_4$SALES ~ subset_4$YEAR)
```

[image]

But the plot doesn't look great. Is there any nicer way of doing this?

Update: plot(subset_4$SALES ~ subset_4$WEEKS)
[image]

Comment: We don't have even a sample of the data nor a picture of the output so it's kinda hard to provide any guidance.

Comment: There are many reasons why a visualization may not look nice. What does the distribution of sales look like? If it exhibits profound variance or skewedness, consider either splitting the data by month, or normalizing it to 100%. Does the graph look like a giant messy blob? Oftentimes, this is referred to as overplotting; you can try to rectify that by reducing the density of visual elements (thorugh grouping, or tweaking the transparency, or limiting the axes limits etc). Do your inputs have classes that make sense? If your dates are characters, the time axis ticks will clutter the plot.

Comment: Can you run the following: `table(subset_4$YEAR)` (to see the distribution of unique values) and `class(subset_4$YEAR)` (to see the class of this column). I'm feeling like you might only have 2 unique values in the entire column.

Comment: I have a weeks column, can I use that?

Comment: You totally can. Try `plot(subset_4$SALES ~ subset_4$WEEKS)` (or whatever the name of the weeks column is), and let us know what it looks like.

Comment: for table(subset_4$YEAR) -> 2016 46417, 2017 51045
class(subset_4$YEAR) -> factor

Comment: @12b345b6b78 I have added the SALES Vs WEEK plot

Comment: You probably don't want to contain datetime data in a factor vector. Consider running `subset_4$YEAR <- as.Date(subset_4$YEAR)`, and then redoing the plot. Btw, before you do that, you need to address 46417 and 51045 because these are clearly not valid dates. How many entries correspond to those dates? If not too many, just drop them

Comment: There's no date, just the year in the year column, i.e 2016,2017

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183425/discussion-between-12b345b6b78-and-user3437212).

Answer (score 0):

You can try ggplot2 library

```
df <- data.frame(sales, year)

ggplot(df, aes(x = sales, y = year, color = year)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("Sales") +
  ylab("Year")
```